# Working with multiple DatePickers in React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native but have been searching for days so if this is easy please let me off the hook.

I have this component:

```
<DatePicker
  signInDate={this.state.signInDate}
  mode="date"
  placeholder="select date"
  format="DD-MM-YYYY"
  minDate="01-01-1950"
  maxDate="01-01-2050"
  androidMode="spinner"
  showIcon={false}
  onDateChange={this.onDateChange('signInDate')}
/>
```

Which uses this class:

```
export default class CPT extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: '', 
      isModalVisible: false, 
      signInDate: "01-01-2000",
      startPump: "01-01-2000",
      endPump: "01-01-2000",
      signOut: "01-01-2000",
      equipmentUsed: '',
    }
  }

  onDateChange = (state) => (event, value) => {
    this.setState({
      state: value });
  }
```

Whenever I update the date the value does change however the display value does not and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I am stuck please, if you can point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Basically I am going to have multiple DatePickers in this popup and will submit them to a DB or a web service when I am done when they hit submit.

I can post the rest of the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is that try using [React-Native-Community-Date-Picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker#getting-started) 
and seems like there are some mismatch between your DatePicker props and your state attributes.

for example if you want to change `signInDate` in your state then your setState should look something like this `this.setState({ signInDate: value });` 
 and `onDateChange` would look like `onDateChange={this.onDateChange}`